# Prestashop CMS page view counter

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm struggling with CMS page view counter.

I'm add new function to **classes/controller/FrontController.php**
like below

```
public static function getCMSViewed($id_cms){
    $viewcms = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT SUM(pv.counter) AS total 
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed pv
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'cms c ON pv.id_page = c.id_cms 
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page p ON pv.id_page = p.id_page
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type pt ON p.id_page_type = pt.id_page_type
        WHERE pt.name = \'cms\'');
        return isset($viewcms['total']) ? $viewcms['total'] : 0;
}
```

and in cms.tpl file i have add **{FrontController::getCMSViewed(Tools::getValue('id_cms'))}**

For now the counter is "working" but showing on all Prestashop CMS pages the same increased value of one of the pages with ID=15

[image]

Comment: Yes. Im bad in MySQL queries :( Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are passing a CMS id into your function, but I do not see you using it anywhere.  You also have the join on cms matching against columns id_page and id_cms.  Which means your query is not going to grab the count you expect.  You want something closer to this.

```
public static function getCMSViewed($id_cms){
$viewcms = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT pv.counter AS total 
    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed pv
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page p ON pv.id_page = p.id_page
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type pt ON p.id_page_type = pt.id_page_type
    WHERE pt.name = \'cms\' AND p.`id_object` = '.intval($id_cms) );
    return isset($viewcms['total']) ? $viewcms['total'] : 0;
}
```

The table `page` holds the id of whatever page it is referencing in the `id_object` column, so you want to match the `$id_cms` you pass in against `p.id_object`.  With that match the sql can return the count directly from the `page_viewed` table.  No need to join in the `cms` table at all.